minikube kubectl get pods all-namespaces - not working
I have setup a minikube on my macos.
But kubectl is not supporting all the commands.
This particular commands is not being supported
minikube kubectl get pods all-namespaces

getting the error -
Error from server (NotFound): pods "all-namespaces" not found

this command is also not working
minikube kubectl get pods --namespace "kube-system"

While this command is working fine
minikube kubectl get pods


The command minikube kubectl get pods all-namespaces that you are using is trying to get the pod named all-namespaces which, of course, doesn’t exist.
Try something like this:
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

or
minikube kubectl -- get pods --all-namespaces

